# Elements in numpy array iteration aren't affected by replace()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, str-replace

Well somewhy an english-languaged CSV exporter made the decimal marker to be a comma. I need those values as floats or rounded as ints. But I can't find a way to do it when the marker is a comma. I went iterating and replacing all comma with dots, but it seems that before I do so some are already with dots and after I do so the ones with commas don't get replaced (it iterates through all the matrix/array/thing and the values are all strings). Please light my mistakes and uncover those mysteries, or point me a better way to do what I need.

I'm using a jupyter notebook, so the following code is from three cells:

```
data = pd.read_csv(processed_data_path, header=None)
print(data)

data = pd.DataFrame.to_numpy(data)

print(data)

for row in data:
  for cell in row:
    cell = cell.replace(",", ".")

print(data)
```

This is what comes out in the first print:

```
        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8    \
0      27,4  27,471  27,458  27,478  27,491  27,491  27,523  27,503  27,516   
1    27,433  27,433  27,433  27,503  27,491   27,51  27,491  27,503  27,516   
2    27,381  27,407    27,4  27,471  27,452  27,458  27,536  27,561  27,497   
3    27,413  27,413  27,426  27,439  27,426  27,491   27,51  27,465  27,471   
4    27,375  27,388  27,355  27,368  27,458  27,433  27,439  27,433  27,458   
..      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   
475   26,17  26,183  26,176   26,17  26,183  26,196  26,222  26,241  26,261   
476   26,17  26,144  26,157  26,183  26,196  26,215  26,222  26,235  26,254   
477   26,17  26,144  26,176  26,183  26,196  26,209  26,235  26,248  26,261   
478  26,157  26,157  26,176  26,196  26,189  26,209  26,235  26,241  26,261   
479  26,105   26,15  26,157  26,183  26,196  26,209  26,228  26,248  26,281   

        9    ...     630     631     632     633     634     635     636  \
0    27,536  ...  32,863  32,863  32,912  32,851  32,845  32,832  32,826   
1    27,516  ...  32,857  32,881  32,832  32,845  32,839  32,851  32,845   
2    27,529  ...  32,851  32,857  32,826  32,857  32,845  32,851  32,839   
3     27,51  ...  32,863  32,826   32,82  32,839  32,796   32,79  32,808   
4    27,355  ...  32,839  32,814  32,802  32,814  32,783   32,82  32,802   
..      ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   
475  26,241  ...   27,31   27,31  27,336  27,349  27,343  27,355  27,317   
476  26,254  ...  27,304   27,31   27,33  27,349  27,355  27,355  27,349   
477  26,274  ...  27,291  27,323  27,349  27,349  27,381  27,362  27,388   
478  26,294  ...  27,297  27,317   27,33  27,349  27,368  27,407    27,4   
479    26,3  ...  27,297  27,323  27,336  27,349  27,394  27,394  27,394   

        637     638     639  
0     32,82  32,814  32,888  
1    32,826  32,826  32,851  
2    32,777   32,82  32,845  
3    32,796   32,82  32,808  
4    32,808  32,802   32,82  
..      ...     ...     ...  
475  27,362   27,33  27,394  
476  27,375  27,381  27,368  
477  27,394  27,388    27,4  
478  27,407    27,4    27,4  
479  27,413  27,407    27,4  

[480 rows x 640 columns]
```

This is what comes out in the second print:

```
[['27.4' '27.471' '27.458' ... '32,82' '32,814' '32,888']
 ['27.433' '27.433' '27.433' ... '32,826' '32,826' '32,851']
 ['27.381' '27.407' '27.4' ... '32,777' '32,82' '32,845']
 ...
 ['26.17' '26.144' '26.176' ... '27,394' '27,388' '27,4']
 ['26.157' '26.157' '26.176' ... '27,407' '27,4' '27,4']
 ['26.105' '26.15' '26.157' ... '27,413' '27,407' '27,4']]
```

This is what comes out in the third print:

```
[['27.4' '27.471' '27.458' ... '32,82' '32,814' '32,888']
['27.433' '27.433' '27.433' ... '32,826' '32,826' '32,851']
['27.381' '27.407' '27.4' ... '32,777' '32,82' '32,845']
...
['26.17' '26.144' '26.176' ... '27,394' '27,388' '27,4']
['26.157' '26.157' '26.176' ... '27,407' '27,4' '27,4']
['26.105' '26.15' '26.157' ... '27,413' '27,407' '27,4']]
```

Comment: Thank both blacksite and Quang Hoang for the answers, I used the last line in the one from the latter to solve it and took good information and counsel from the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pandas replace function:

```
data = pd.read_csv(processed_data_path, header=None)
data = data.replace(',','.', regex=True)
```

Also, consider the decimal option which handles the `,` for you:

```
data = pd.read_csv(processed_data_path, header=None, decimal=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for row in data:
  for cell in row:
    cell = cell.replace(",", ".")
```

These lines are modifying the variable `cell`, which isn't "attached" at all to your `data` object. You're literally just replacing `,` with `.` in some variable `cell`. You could do something like this, which replaces all instances of `,` with `.` in the `pandas.DataFrame` *before* converting to NumPy (although it's not clear why you're opting for the base NumPy representation of these data in the first place).

```py
data = pd.read_csv(processed_data_path, header=None)
data = data.replace(',', '.')
```

If you *really* wanted to modify the NumPy object itself in this iterative way, you could do something like this:

```py
# For each row
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    # For each column
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        data[i, j] = data[i, j].replace(',', '.')
```

**Although it is highly recommended to stick with the "vectorized" `pandas.DataFrame.replace` approach shown above.**

Comment: The reason I moved it to numpy is because the pandas format proved less straight-throug than numpy arrays when it's about accessing positions (I'm getting a "key error", still don't understand completely). But anyway I'll round these values and match to grayscale to see what comes out, so numpy seems the one for that as well.